# How do I trigger a lightbox gallery in html or javascript for a single image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is my question,

Can I place a script or a code of some sort next to an image to make it pop out in a lightbox, without messing with the css? Just a simple single image that when clicked on just pops out in a lightbox.

Sort of like this:

```
<a href="url"><img src="image"></a>
```

But instead of ref to a url, I would like to make a full screen lightbox pop out. So the user doesn't have to click back or open another tab.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can, I like Fancybox as an versatile jQuery tool with many functions and options. See [here](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#examples) for examples.